# Nginx Request Routing based on body param

Tags: nginx, routes, nginx-location

I am grouping the servers in nginx as explained [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html). I want to route my requests to different server groups based on the param in request body.
Is there a way I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a form input sent via POST, then no. The simplest solution is to make the variable sent via GET (incorporate it in the `<form>` tag's `action` attribute) or to send it as header.
All variables sent as GET are available via `$arg_`*name*. Headers are available through `$http_`*name*.